# Populating a DropDownList with NpgsqlDataReader - Selected Value is Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am attempting to populate my `DropDownLists` from a `NpgsqlDataReader`. These lists are coming from different tables. Page is loading a Product from the Product Table with list from Department Table and Group Table. Issue is when page loads, `DropDownList` does not load list with the selected value chosen by default, but rather just loads the list from top to bottom. Upon inspecting the source html, There is no selected value.
But when I debug the `DataReader` has the appropriate records from the list tables.

In my controller I have

```
 NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand
            ("SELECT * FROM q_product  " +                
            "LEFT JOIN q_department ON (q_product.department_guid = q_department.department_guid)" +
            "LEFT JOIN q_group ON (q_product.q_groupid = q_group.q_groupid)" +                
            "ORDER BY q_guid ASC " +
            "FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY"
            , connection);

        NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var productPage = new ProductViewModel();
            productPage.q_guid = Guid.Parse(dr["q_guid"].ToString());
            productPage.q_description = dr["q_description"].ToString();
            productPage.q_barcode = dr["q_barcode"].ToString();
            productPage.viewDepartment = dr["q_name"].ToString();
            productPage.viewGroup = dr["q_groupname"].ToString();

            //other columns...
```

Populating dropdownlist in controller

```
var pagedProduct = new PaginatedList<ProductViewModel>(viewModelQuery, currentPageIndex, pageSize);

        ViewBag.department_guid = new SelectList(db.q_department, "department_guid", "q_name", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().viewDepartment);            
        ViewBag.q_groupid = new SelectList(db.q_group, "q_groupid", "q_groupname", pagedProduct.SingleOrDefault().viewGroup);
```

Debugging to see what the values are before page is rendered

[image: Debug Screenshot]

In my View (cshtml page) I have

```
@Html.DropDownList("department_guid", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownList("q_groupid", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Which results in the list just getting loaded with chossing/selecting the appropriate value.

[image: Default loaded selection]

- Department should have Department 1 loaded/selected
- Group should have Liquor loaded/selected

So if the lists have the approproiate values in controller before rendering, I take it I am missing a step on in the razor code to get the appropriate selection? How can I resolve/fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved issue.

Error was on these lines

```
productPage.viewDepartment = dr["q_description"].ToString();
productPage.viewGroup = dr["q_barcode"].ToString();
```

it was a matter of typing the KEY columns rather than the text columns. An oversight on my end.

```
productPage.viewDepartment= dr["department_guid"].ToString();
productPage.viewGroup= dr["q_groupid"].ToString();
```